# Когда надо использовать use для namespace?

Tags: php, namespace

Заметил что Шторм выдаёт информацию что use не имеет эффекта никакого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почитал доку http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php но так и не понять в каком случае ничего не нбудет работать без `use` как алиас понятно его можно использовать что бы сократить длинное имя. В обычном случае когда делаю `$obj - new \Model\MyClass();` непонятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть класс

```
namespace Model;

class MyClass{
.....
```

Тогда в другом пространстве имен для использования этого класса вам придется либо использовать полное имя класса(с его пространством имен), либо можно использовать `use Model\MyClass;` и после этого, при обращении к классу, пространство имен не писать.

Т.е. или так

```
use Model\MyClass;
$myClass = new MyClass();
```

или так

```
$myClass = mew \Model\MyClass();
```

Эти два варианта использования абсолютно равнозначны.

**UPD** если у вас в двух пространствах имен присутствуют классы с одинаковым именем, то при попытке использовать и тот и тот PHP выдаст `fatal error`.

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20961cc76a3d781d93975ea1122ea1cc9c0caaa7)

**UPD** Обратите внимание, что при использовании полного имени класса, если перед пространством имен не поставить `\`("корневое" пространство имен), то имя будет считаться относительно текущего пространства имен.

Т.е. вот тут

```
namespace C;
$a = new B\A();
```

Будет считаться, что вы написали так:

```
namespace C;
$a = new \C\B\A();
```

Comment: А понял, один вопрос только остался если у меня 2 класса с одним именем в разных пространствах имён и я делаю `namespace A; namespace B;` а потом пишу класс который и там и там есть `$var = new DoubleClass();` то будет ошибка? Как бы случайно имена не перепутать... Или к каждому классу лучше дописывать его принадлежность даже если они в разных папках? Например ControllerUser, ModelUser ?

Comment: @fosh4455 такого лучше не допускать. Но если все же пришлось использовать два "одинаковых" класса из разных пространств имен, то один из них(а лучше оба) используйте по полному имени.

Comment: @fosh4455 @rjhdby, так вроде можно alias задать.... соответственно для одинаковых классов можно написать `use A\B\Classname as FirstClass; use Z\X\Classname as SecondClass;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да но если я сделаю `use A\B\Classname as OneClass; use Z\X\Classname as OneClass;` то должна быть какая-то ошибка... А по невнимательности это возможно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно, но лично мне такой подход как-то не очень. imho так сказать

Comment: @fosh4455 будет тот же `falat error`

Comment: @fosh4455 по невнимательности можно сделать всё что угодно. из-за невнимательности в принципе в коде много ошибок и возникает. так что это не особо аргумент.  но при данной невнимательности возникнет ошибка, которую быстро можно пофиксить

Comment: @rjhdby иногда так бывает. например когда сторонние либы используешь. так что от этого не уйти, в принципе. но зато можно быть готовым. просто если путь до класса будет большим - использовать алиасы благоразумнее, чем полные пути, кмк

Answer (score 2):

В пространстве имен все относительно.
Например, Вы находитесь в пространстве имен `namespace \models\`

а) И пытаетесь использовать класс User, находящийся в том же namespace, то use использовать не нужно. Можно обращаться напрямую `$user = new User();`

б) Пытаетесь использовать класс User, находящийся в namespace \components\
Тогда надо  писать `$user = new \components\User()` в классе `MyClass`;

Или, чтобы не писать всегда в разных местах кода путь к классу, один раз указать `use components\User`

А потом вызов станет короче: `$user = new User();` 
Почему при использовании use не обязателен ведущий слэш - я не знаю, но можно его не указывать, а можно писать `use \components\User` . Это равносильно.